# Set default value of an element in Zend_Form by reference from the controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-form

Via the command line I set up a new form called BookSlot:

```
zf create form BookSlot
```

Which most of you may know, creates a form directory in the application directory of the Zend framework.

In the init method of the form, I added a text element called time and given it the label 'time':

```
$time = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('time');
$this->addElement($time);
$time->setLabel('Time');
```

I need it to have a default value that cannot be changed by the user so I add:

```
$time->setValue($value);
```

In my controller I create a function to get the book slot form above:

```
public function getBookSlotForm(){
        return new Application_Form_BookSlot();
    }
```

I also have a book slot action in my index controller.

I assign the form to a variable and make it passable to the view in the book slot action:

```
$form = $this->getBookSlotForm();
    $this->view->form = $form;
```

In the same book slot action, I have an id variable which is dynamically generated but for this assume its 5:

```
$id = 5;
```

How do I get the value of `$id` to be the default value of `$time` in my book slot form above? Also, I want to make it so that the user cannot change this value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the user can not change the value use the readOnly attribute. In your form class

```
$time->setAttrib('readonly', 'readonly');
```

To assign your id as the default value of your time field, in your action

```
$form->time->setValue($id);
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought It would be more complicated than simply passing the variable that literally.